# Amazon S3 static index.html not changing to homepage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a new home page / index.html into Amazon S3.  The home page is not changing to this new page - it is still displaying the original simple 'Hello World' page.

I deleted the old index.html and uploaded my new index.html with no luck.  The endpoint page is working correctly.  I have created Alias in Route 53.

I've made the DNS changes and think I have everything in place, just need to switch some setting - what is this setting?

Comment: It could be that DNS takes a while to propagate due to downstream servers caching lookups, or it would be your browser cache. Wait a day and clear your browser cache.

Comment: What has DNS got to do with page? @Mark you have CloudFront in front of S3 as per `Via:1.1 f6ea932c4737d64ad2a25ff58b14d9f2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)`. [Flush the CloudFront cache](https://www.google.com/?q=invalidate+cloudfront+cache).

Comment: Thanks DF and TJ.  TJ, that was the answer I needed.  I'm new to S3, Route 53 and CloudFront so still learning things.  I cleared the cache and I'm good to go.  Thanks again.